# Does cuda memcpy from host to host perform synchronization?

Tags: cuda

If I call cudaMemcpy from host memory to host memory, will it first synchronize the device? Is there any difference between the cuda memcpy call and the ordinary C++ function memcpy? I know that in case I want to do a memcpy 2D between host to host, I have to use the cuda call, since there is no such function in C++. Is there any other ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I call cudaMemcpy from host memory to host memory, will it first synchronize the device?

I verified that `cudaMemcpy()` with `cudaMemcpyHostToHost` does synchronize with the following code:

```
#include <cuda.h>

#define check_cuda_call(ans) { _check((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void _check(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line)
{
  if (code != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr,"CUDA Error: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
    exit(code);
  }
}

__device__ clock_t offset;

__global__ void clock_block(clock_t clock_count)
{
  clock_t start_clock = clock();
  clock_t clock_offset = 0;
  while (clock_offset < clock_count) {
    clock_offset = clock() - start_clock;
  }
  offset = clock_offset;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *A;
  check_cuda_call(cudaMallocHost(&A, 1 * sizeof(int)));
  int *B;
  check_cuda_call(cudaMallocHost(&B, 1 * sizeof(int)));

  clock_block<<<1,1>>>(1000 * 1000 * 1000);

  //check_cuda_call(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
  check_cuda_call(cudaMemcpy(&A, &B, 1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToHost));
}
```

With a blocking call after the kernel launch, the app waits for around 1 second on my card. Without a blocking call, it exits immediately.

> Is there any difference between the cuda memcpy call and the ordinary C++ function memcpy?

Yes, the synchronization, which also causes the `cudaMemcpy()` with `cudaMemcpyHostToHost` to be able to return errors from previous async calls, makes it different from plain `memcpy()`.

> I know that in case I want to do a memcpy 2D between host to host, I have to use the cuda call, since there is no such function in C++. Is there any other ones?

You might be able to use `cudaMemcpyAsync()` with `cudaMemcpyHostToHost` to do copies on the host without blocking the CPU, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Good Lord. If you want host-to-host memcpy without synchronization, *call memcpy()*!!

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware, are you referring to my last comment about `cudaMemcpyAsync()`? What I meant with that is that it looks like you might be able to run a `memcpy()` that is async with respect to the CPU (as if you were running it in another CPU thread or process).

Comment: https://www.theinquirer.net/w-images/bfff8015-d483-4def-9bcb-11c1023f24b3/0/sandybrdiag1a-540x334.png?1453339152 does it add more bandwidth on top of a concurrent memcpy() when used in a numa system, using an extra qpi link through pci-e?